# ASP.NET - Access Session from static method/static class?

Tags: asp.net, session, static

I would like to access the session object without passing it to my static helper function.

This is so I can save and load things from the session object automatically with minimum extra fluff.

Is it possible/how can I access the session object from within a static method in a static class?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)