# Get Session variable inside a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, session, session-variables

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using SurelyKnown.Core;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] 
    public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {
        int newOrgID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uOrgID"].ToString());
```

The error is on the last line

```
 CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.get'
```

WHat should I do to get the session value inside the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586564/asp-net-access-session-from-static-method-static-class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Session`

```
int newOrgID=0;
if(HttpContext.Current.Session["uOrgID"]!=null)
{
  int.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Session["uOrgID"].ToString(),out newOrgID);
}
```

Comment: @Mark - The Session is page property and it cannot be used outside the   Page class or in static method so you have get reference of Session object from the context via HttpContext.Current.Session method.

Answer (score 0):

check for null before using it, something like this:

```
if(Session["uOrgID"] != null)
{
  int newOrgID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["uOrgID"].ToString());
}
```

You should also read this article to really understand how to access Session state from web services (including web and page methods): [Using ASP.NET Session State in a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx)

Comment: That's actually not a good practice. Session["uOrgID"] can be removed before you get a chance to parse it. You should do string uOrgID = Session["uOrgID"] as string; if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uOrgID)) ....